# backup issue about openstack disk

Tags: backup, openstack, volume

In OpenStack, is it theoretically possible to simultaneously initiate requests for creating a new cloud disk backup (e.g., Backup B) and deleting ten existing cloud disk backups (e.g., Backup A……), all of which are associated with the same cloud disk.

it is great if the two actions can be done at the same time